# How to archive modified files between two git branch using command git archive?

Tags: git, shell

I use such a command to archive modified files between master and HEAD:

```
git archive --format=zip -o diff_archive.zip HEAD `git diff --name-only master..HEAD`
```

However, if there is no modified file, all files in working copy would be archived, is there any way
to avoid this?

Now,what I could do is to use a dummy file, and change the command like this:

```
git archive --format=zip -o diff_archive.zip HEAD dummy_file `git diff --name-only master..HEAD`
```

It solves my problem, but not elegantly, for dummy_file would always be archived.

Comment: you could run your diff | wc -l and only proceed to the archive step if >0

Comment: This operation isn't safe if files can have names that include shell metacharacters since `git diff` will not quote them appropriately for use with `git archive`. You would need to use `git diff -z` to get it to do that but then I don't believe `git archive` would understand the list of files anymore. And `git diff -z` doesn't quote most shell metacharacters so doesn't help there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't mind the fact that this operation is not at all safe with even slightly oddly named files or that include whitespace. Then you can do the following:

```
files=$(git diff --name-only master..HEAD)
git archive --format=zip -o diff_archive.zip HEAD ${files:-NO_SUCH_FILE}
```

and `git archive` will error on the non-existent file. (This uses the `Use Default Value` version of `Parameter Expansion`.)

If you would rather avoid the error then use `git diff --exit-code`:

if ! _files=$(git diff --exit-code --name-only master..HEAD); then
    git archive --format=zip -o diff_archive.zip HEAD $files
fi

(This needs `!` to invert the exit code because `git diff` (like `diff` itself) exits with `1` when there are differences and `0` when there aren't any).

Answer (score 0):

Here is command to archive changes between *master* and *HEAD*, also works with filenames that includes spaces, quotes, double quotes, any special characters:

```
git diff --name-only -z --diff-filter=ACMRT master..HEAD | xargs -0 git archive -o diff_archive.zip HEAD --
```